# using _.where with array underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am new to underscore.js
I have two objects `TOWERS` and `UNITS`

```
var TOWERS = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "A",
        project: 1,
        floors: 8
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "B",
        project: 1,
        floors: 8   
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "C",
        project: 1,
        floors: 8   
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "D",
        project: 1,
        floors: 8   
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "E",
        project: 1,
        floors: 8   
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        name: "F",
        project: 2,
        floors: 8   
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        name: "G",
        project: 2,
        floors: 8   
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        name: "H",
        project: 2,
        floors: 8   
    }
]

var UNITS = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "101",
        unittype: 1,
        tower: 1,
        floor: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "102",
        unittype: 2,
        tower: 1,
        floor: 1
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "101",
        unittype: 1,
        tower: 2,
        floor: 1
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "102",
        unittype: 2,
        tower: 2,
        floor: 1
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "101",
        unittype: 3,
        tower: 3,
        floor: 1
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "102",
        unittype: 3,
        tower: 8,
        floor: 1
    }
]
```

I am selecting `TOWERS` **id** which has `project:1` using:

```
var getTowers = _.where(TOWERS, {project:1});
var getUniqueTowers = _.chain(getTowers).pluck("id").unique().compact().value();
```

I got `[1,2,3,4,5]`
Now I want to select `UNITS` which tower's value is in `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Is there any way to use `_.where` like below?

```
_.where(UNITS, {tower:[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.filter` with `.indexOf`, like so

```
var units = _.chain(UNITS)
    .filter(function (unit) {
        return _.indexOf(getUniqueTowers, unit.tower) >= 0;         
    })
    .value()
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/Lc6cojee/1/)

Version without underscore

```
var units = UNITS.filter(function (unit) {
    return getUniqueTowers.indexOf(unit.tower) >= 0;            
})
```